# Creating multiple objects using dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have the following implementation and method. When called the `setPaymentInfo` method is called and a dictionary is an argument, the method then creates a new instance of `PaypalPaymentInfo` and then the values are set. This all works great.

What I would like to be able to do now, is to be able to pass in multiple dictionaries into the method and create multiple instances of `PaypalPaymentInfo` and fill the values. So essentially an "array" of dictionaries, if you will.

```
@implementation PaypalPaymentInfo

@synthesize paymentCurrency, paymentAmount, itemDesc, recipient, merchantName;

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.paymentCurrency = nil;
    self.paymentAmount = nil;
    self.itemDesc = nil;
    self.recipient = nil;
    self.merchantName = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end

- (void) setPaymentInfo:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    self.paymentInfo = nil;
    self.paymentInfo = [[PaypalPaymentInfo alloc] init];

    [self.paymentInfo setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:options];
}
```

Google searches haven't been very helpful, this kind of situation is hard to put into few enough words to search for...

Thanks

Comment: i am not sure what you want to achieve? you want to add dic in array? lets just say like dic for 1 person's info and 2 person info and all is in array thats what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a mutable array to hold the PaypalPaymetntInfo objects, and I've called that paymentInfoArray in my example. Then you just need to pass an array (of dictionaries) instead of a dictionary, and loop through the array to get the dictionaries inside.

```
- (void) setPaymentInfo:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withArray:(NSArray*)options
{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in options){
       PaypalPaymentInfo *paymentInfo = [[PaypalPaymentInfo alloc] init];
       [paymentInfo setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
       self.paymentInfoArray addObject:paymentInfo];
    }
}
```